# A1200 Amitek Hawk, Guru Meditation 8000 000B when loading games from Gotek

Tags: ram, amiga-1200

Hardware:

- A1200
- CF 4GB (sys part 800MB)
- KS 3.1 40.68
- ClassicWB
- Amitek Hawk 4MB, FPU 68882, oscillator 28MHz
- Gotek, Flash Floppy 2.1.4

When Amitek is used the machine boots from Gotek USB adf file the game menu (not gotek, but actual loaded game) will load (North and South, few others), but when actually trying to start a game it crashes with Guru Meditation error [8000 000B](http://www.amigahistory.plus.com/8b.html). Without Amitek it works normally.

It looks like the machine never been recapped. Is this the only thing I should consider (Hawk uses extra juice as I understand) or would it be to libs as per link (mine were copied from ClassicWB)? PSU shows corrects values on multimeter.

[image]

Comment: You just added the Amitek Hawk, it started to have this problem, or the problem is just when you started trying this game?

Comment: Happens with hawk

Comment: i know tell more

Answer (score 1):

I think the first question to answer is whether booting from a game floppy image via the Gotek is the best way to achieve game compatibility with an expanded Amiga. In my experience, compatibility is better when using WHDLoad images instead of unmodified floppy images for expanded Amigas.

You mentioned you have a 4GB IDE-CF HDD. If you already have WHDLoad installed, what has been your experience trying to run games through that route, with and without your Hawk expansion unit?

If WHDLoad has not been tried with the Hawk, I recommend trying this first. If you get good results, then your problem is solved. If the Hawk still give you problems, I would try swapping out the memory on the Hawk.

As far as the recommendation to run "SetPatch" in your link, that may be important too. And this is another reason you should be booting from the CF card into a properly patched environment for your expansion hardware. WHDLoad will support launching games from such a patched environment, and this is one of the reasons it provides for better compatibility with expanded Amigas.

Comment: I wanted to test the unit before selling. Currently it has gotek, but will be selling with stock floppy and the Hawk as bundle. WHDLoad works okay.

Comment: If you un-bundle, then the buyer won't expect you to test any integrated solution for them. Like I said, best option for any Amiga user will be un-expanded w/ floppies or expanded w/ WHDLoad setup.